# Form Does Not Appear to be STAThread

Tags: .net, forms, visual-studio-2015, sta

I am profiling a colleague's C# application.  The VS2015 analysis tool shows that 33% of exclusive samples occur in System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run.  Nearly all of the computation occurs inside a click event, and the form is unresponsive as you would expect.  I searched through the code to make sure no threads were being created explicitly.

I was trying to figure out where that 33% was being used.  When I stop the application randomly, it's always in windowThreadProc (file SystemEvents.cs) waiting on messages.  I can step through the loop even as the main computation is running; so, it's clearly on a separate thread.

The function EnsureSystemEvents is run before Main.  I can step through it and see it's spinning up a thread for windowThreadProc.  I can see the [STAThread] attribute above Main.

Shouldn't there be only one thread?  Please explain.

Comment: I don't have much of a grasp of the apartment model.  Partly, I was looking at the code in EnsureSystemEvents, which checks the apartment state.  If the apartment is STA, it runs the message pump on the current thread.

Comment: It should be spending 99% of its time there.  But sure, when you have a Click event handler that turns the UI catatonic then it will be less.  You must profile only the Release build with the Visual Studio Hosting process option disabled.

Comment: It didn't make much of a difference in the profiling results.  The threading of the message pump was the same.